# Alter log file date with the command sed?

Tags: json, linux, logging, sed, logfile

i have the following line multiple times in a log file with other data.
And i like to analyze this data by importing the json part to a mongodb first and the run selected queries over it.

```
DEBUG 2015-04-18 23:13:23,374 [TEXT] (Class.java:19) - {"a":"1", "b":"2", ...}
```

To alter the data just to get the json part i use:

```
cat mylog.log | sed "s/DEBUG.*19) - //g" > mylog.json
```

The main problem here is, that is like to add the date and time part as well and as an additional json value to get something like this:

```
{"date": "2015-04-18", "time":"23:13:26,374", "a":"1", "b":"2", ...}
```

Here is the main question. How can i do this by using the linux console and the comman sed? Or by an alternative console command?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a very rigid format, you could probably use sed like so:

```
sed 's/DEBUG \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\).*19) - {/{ "date": "\1", "time": "\2", /' mylog.log
```

Where `[^ ]*` matches a sequence of non-space characters and `\(regex\)` is a capturing group that makes a matched string available for use in the replacement as `\1`, `\2`, and so forth depending on its position. You can see these used in the replacement part.

If it were me, though, I'd use Perl for its ability to split a line into fields and match non-greedily:

```
perl -ape 's/.*?{/{ "date": "$F[1]", "time": "$F[2]", /' mylog.log
```

The latter replaces everything up to the first `{` (because `.*?` matches non-greedily) and replaces it with the string you want. `$F[1]` and `$F[2]` are the second and third whitespace-delimited field in the line; `-a` makes Perl split the line into the `@F` array this way.